# Download Whole OBS(S3) Bucket Using SDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to use Huawei OBS service. It is alike S3. SDK is very similar to AWS S3. So if s3 has solution OBS should have too. So if you have a solution on S3. It can work too.

I have a bucket that has 20k objects in it. I need to download that data with using python sdk ONLY.

I tried to list the objects and download 1 by 1 but only first 1k data is gathered.

List Objects --> https://support.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/sdk-python-devg-obs/obs_22_0805.html

With a for each Download Objects --> https://support.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/sdk-python-devg-obs/obs_22_0909.html

Comment: Why are you giving minus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation page you linked says *"You can use this API to list objects in a bucket. By default, a maximum of 1000 objects are listed."* That's why you are only receiving 1000 objects.

AWS has a `list_objects_v2()` command that can use a `ContinuationToken` to obtain more objects in a listing, but that might not be available in OBS.

Instead, you probably need to **call the function again** and pass the last `Key` of the previous result set in the `marker` field because the documentation says: *"Specifies a marker when listing objects in a bucket. With a marker configured, objects after this marker will be returned in alphabetical order."*

Comment: Thank you it worked. I append values to an array and set marker as array[999]. Recursively i can get all object keys.